# Could not load file or assembly error

Tags: .net, application-blocks

I got an error Message like

> "Could not load file or >assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.ExceptionManagement.Interfaces, 
>   Version=1.0.2732.30552, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified."

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please show the line of code that throws this exception with additional lines for context so that we may perhaps see what is happening leading up to your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [assembly binding log viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) to find out what exactly is failing to load and fix that.

The error explains exactly what is going on - the assembly specified cannot be found, or one of its dependencies cannot be found. You might have an assembly of that name but wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.ExceptionManagement isn't compatible with .Net framework 4.6.2.
If your application is deployed on a server with framework 4.6.2 or later, the application will stop working and the w3wp process crashes causing the app pool to stop.
You have to change the code and use log4net instead. The application will work fine on framework 4.6.2 once the exception manager code is removed.

Comment: Hm. I don't see any information about them using framework 4.6.2, how are you so sure this will solve their issue?